# I have an iphone 4s and it wont unlock

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have an iphone 4s, and it will not unlock, using my normal pin. I took it to a computer store, but they want 60$/hr for a 4hour minimum of work. This is more than I can afford.

Is there any other way to get this phone unlocked? I do not want to do a factory reset, there are pictures, and phone numbers, that I do not want to loose. I looked around on other sites, and those sites look sketchy.

I don't want to jail-brake the phone, I just want to get my files, and be able to use it again.

Comment: Do a back up first, then restore after it's unlocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way to unlock your phone other than to do a factory reset / restore backup.

You can have your [local Apple Store employees](http://www.apple.com/retail/) help you, or if you change your mind, you can follow one of these two Apple support pages on factory resetting / restoring a backup of your phone.

- [Erase and reset your phone to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274)
- [Restore a backup of your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184)

Good luck!

Comment: I live in Maine, I think the Closest Apple Store is Boston or something.

Comment: @j0h Try the Maine Mall. I live in the Portland area, it is close to there.

Comment: Brewer ME, pretty interesting. And thats a heck of a lot closer than Boston

Comment: @j0h Glad I was able to help – good luck!